# Record Windows session to remote website

Tags: windows, debugging, thick-client

I have some solutions running on third-party systems, and every so often a customer specific error occurs. Unfortunately, due both to the amount of customer customization and the access difficulties, we are not really able to replicate these (rather trivial) errors. Is there a application, free or paid, that can easily run on a Windows server, record all activity and send back a video to our servers?